# Count number of records where all their relative dependant attributes belong to a specific list

Tags: sql, sql-server

In order to explain my issue, I present the star schema as the following :

**SaleItem** (fact)

- SaleID (key)
- ProductID (key)
- Quantity
- SalePrice

**Sale** (dim)

- SaleID (key)
- SaleDate

**Product** (dim)

- ProductID (key)
- CategoryID (fk)
- ProductName

**Category** (dim)

- CategoryID (key)
- CategoryName

I want to count the number of **Sales** (SaleID) where the **CategoryId is Only = 4**, in **2011**.

I tried doing this :

```
SELECT        COUNT(DISTINCT SaleItem.SaleID) AS [Number of Bread-Only 2011 Sales]
FROM            Product INNER JOIN
                         SaleItem ON Product.ProductID = SaleItem.ProductID INNER JOIN
                         Sale ON SaleItem.SaleID = Sale.SaleID
WHERE        (YEAR(Sale.SaleDate) = '2011') AND (SaleItem.ProductID IN
                             (SELECT        ProductID
                               FROM            Product
                               WHERE        (CategoryID = '4')))
```

The problem with this, I get SaleIDs where at **least one** ProductID relating to them is related to CategoryID=4 like this:

[image]

But I want **all the related ProductIDs** are related to **CategoryID=4** or don't count them.

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

```
SELECT COUNT (X.SaleID) AS [Number of Bread-Only 2011 Sales] FROM 
((SELECT        DISTINCT SaleItem.SaleID
FROM            Product INNER JOIN
                         SaleItem ON Product.ProductID = SaleItem.ProductID INNER JOIN
                         Sale ON SaleItem.SaleID = Sale.SaleID
WHERE        (YEAR(Sale.SaleDate) = '2011') AND (SaleItem.ProductID IN
                             (SELECT        ProductID
                               FROM            Product
                               WHERE        (CategoryID = '4'))))
EXCEPT
(SELECT        DISTINCT SaleItem.SaleID
FROM            Product INNER JOIN
                         SaleItem ON Product.ProductID = SaleItem.ProductID INNER JOIN
                         Sale ON SaleItem.SaleID = Sale.SaleID
WHERE        (YEAR(Sale.SaleDate) = '2011') AND (SaleItem.ProductID IN
                             (SELECT        ProductID
                               FROM            Product  
                               WHERE        (CategoryID <> '4'))))) AS X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is how it should be done :

```
(SELECT        DISTINCT SaleItem.SaleID
FROM            Product INNER JOIN
                         SaleItem ON Product.ProductID = SaleItem.ProductID INNER JOIN
                         Sale ON SaleItem.SaleID = Sale.SaleID
WHERE        (YEAR(Sale.SaleDate) = '2011') AND (SaleItem.ProductID IN
                             (SELECT        ProductID
                               FROM            Product
                               WHERE        (CategoryID = '4'))))
EXCEPT
(SELECT        DISTINCT SaleItem.SaleID
FROM            Product INNER JOIN
                         SaleItem ON Product.ProductID = SaleItem.ProductID INNER JOIN
                         Sale ON SaleItem.SaleID = Sale.SaleID
WHERE        (YEAR(Sale.SaleDate) = '2011') AND (SaleItem.ProductID IN
                             (SELECT        ProductID
                               FROM            Product  
                               WHERE        (CategoryID <> '4'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want to count the number of sales for category 4 products soled in 2011. if thats the case then, I guess the below can produce the required result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM SaleItem as a
  JOIN Sale     as b ON b.SaleID = a.SaleID AND YEAR(b.SaleDate) = 2011
  JOIN Product  as c ON c.ProductID = a.ProductID and c.CategoryID = 4
```